# Manually closing of Jquery Dialog window

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, window

I'm trying to manually close a `Jquery Dialog window` on button click without using the `$('#id').dialog('close')` command.

The reason is that I make an ajax call as the dialog window is opened and so the .dialog no longer works on the response. My issue is that I've managed to close the dialog window manually by removing the divs for the window itself and the overlay, but for some reason the background form still remains disabled.

Even though everything seems to be removed, it is still not possible to click on buttons or form fields so I'm wondering if I am missing some piece. Does anyone know what else Jquery uses to disable the background on a modal dialog window?

**Update**
I tried returning the view from the HomeController in an effort to somehow refresh the page after manually removing the overlay and window. The page is still disabled though and I have yet to find out why.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just create a scope where both the ajax call and the show dialog function reside in?

Comment: How do you load your ajax? Normally close should work after this call... And for the forms which become unresponsive, this is probably due to some overlay, isn't it?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would create such a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like the ajax call is modifying the page in some way that changes the div upon which the jQueryUI dialog is based. After you have invoked the `dialog` method on a div (or other element) it effectively belongs to jQueryUI and you must not touch it until after you have called `.dialog("destroy")`. You must either:

1. Ensure that the div, and the markup that jQueryUI adds around it are not touched by the result of the ajax call or
2. Just *before* the div is modified, call `$("#id).dialog("destroy");` then recreate the dialog all over again after the ajax call has done its thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.parent.jQuery('#ModalDialog').dialog('destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a click function to button

```
$("#button").click(function()
{
$("#id").dialog('close');
});
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

or maybe I don't understand your question :)

Comment: I've already done these. The close function no longer works after an Ajax call because the dialog window is no longer instantiated. Reinstantiating the dialog window causes undesired effects.

Comment: provide me the javascript code (ajax with the dialog only) to see the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this doesn't work:

```
    $("#modal").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true
    });

    // to open
    $("#modal").dialog("open"); 

    // to close
    $("#modal").dialog("close");
```